POST request not working in React Native Expo, but GET request is working
I'm trying to log in with a POST method, but the data in the request is not being received by the server. I tried it in Postman, and the data was sent successfully. I first tried with Axios, then with Fetch API, but neither worked. However, when I tried it with a GET request, it worked perfectly.
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { appPackageName, ApiKey, ApiServer } from '@/constants';
import { MyObject } from '@/interface';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const headers: MyObject = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
  headers['APP_PACKAGE_NAME'] = appPackageName;
}

This is the Axios request:
export async function postData(relativeUrl: string, requestData: MyObject): Promise<MyObject> {
  try {
    headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${ApiKey}`;

    console.log({ ...requestData });

    const response = await axios.post(
      `${ApiServer}/${relativeUrl}`,
      { ...requestData }, // I tried with JSON.stringify(requestData) and without the spread or stringify as well
      {
        headers: headers,
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle the error
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
}

This is the Fetch request:
export async function postData(relativeUrl: string, requestData: MyObject): Promise<MyObject> {
  try {
    headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${ApiKey}`;

    console.log({ ...requestData });

    const response = await fetch(`${ApiServer}/${relativeUrl}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    });

    console.log(response);

    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
}

This is the GET request method:
export async function getData(relativeUrl: string, requestData: MyObject): Promise<MyObject> {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${ApiServer}/${relativeUrl}`,
      {
        headers: headers,
        params: requestData,
      }
    );
    console.log(response.data);

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
}

This is the request header of the browser:
POST /public/auth/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9016
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_CODE
Content-Length: 97
Origin: http://localhost:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8081/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Priority: u=0

This is the request header of Postman:
Cookie: PHPSESSID=vcug376r85rus7fj3aep0pivmm
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: <calculated when request is sent>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>
Content-Length: <calculated when request is sent>
Host: <calculated when request is sent>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.39.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_CODE
Content-Type: application/json

This is the php CORS Check
/**
 * Set up headers that handle API requests
 */
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/env-var.php';

$headers = getallheaders();

// Get the request's Origin header
$origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] ?? '';

// Handle preflight requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, HTTP_X_APP_PACKAGE_NAME");

    if (isset($headers['Authorization']) || isset($headers['Credentials'])) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    }

    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400'); // Cache for 1 day
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(0);
}

// Set general CORS headers
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(preg_match('/development/',ENV)){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
} 
else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_APP_PACKAGE_NAME']) && in_array($_SERVER['APP_PACKAGE_NAME'], $allowedApps))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && in_array($origin, $allowedOrigins))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $origin");
else {
    http_response_code(401);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Unauthorized Access']);
    exit;
}

// Allow credentials if the request includes Authorization or Credentials header
if (isset($headers['Authorization']) || isset($headers['Credentials'])) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
}

// Allow specified methods
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

// Allow specific headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, X-Custom-Header");

// Cache for 1 day
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');


Make sure that your server's CORS configuration allows POST requests from your client domain. CORS issues may not affect GET requests but can affect POST requests.

@mrSoh I've added server cors check script

"This is the request header of Postman:" - why are there two Content-Type headers in there, with different values? "but the data in the request is not being received by the server" - how exactly did you try to access it on the server side?

using var_dump($_POST) on the server, which was empty on request from the browser and wasn't from postman

PHP does not populate $_POST, when you send application/json. That it worked from postman, must be due to that fact that it was multipart/form-data in that case. If you send JSON, you need to read it yourself from the input stream - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867369/1427878

Thank you @CBroe, changing the content type to multipart/form-data at both sides solved the problem, Thank you.
